# Inserting the SQL query result in Excel

Tags: mysql, sql-server, vba, excel

I am using the below SQL query which is returing multiple rows and coloumns in result, when i am trying to pass those in excel i am not able to do it

Code:

```
Set com = QCConnection.Command
com.CommandText = "select RN_TESTER_NAME as 'Tester, sum(case when RN_STATUS='Passed' then cnt else 0 end), sum(case when RN_STATUS='Failed' then cnt else 0 end)from (select count(*) cnt, RN_STATUS,RN_TESTER_NAME from  RUN Where RN_Execution_Date = '5/17/2017'group by RN_STATUS,RN_TESTER_NAME) as RUN group by RN_TESTER_NAME order by RN_TESTER_NAME"
Set RecSet = com.Execute
For Col = 0 To RecSet.ColCount - 1
   Sheet4.Cells(Col + 1, 7) = RecSet.FieldValue(Col)
Debug.Print Sheet4.Cells(Col + 1, 7)
Next
```

I am getting the result as the below
User1 
2 
3

I want the result in this manner (please note this is the way qc is showing me the result
User1   2    3  (2 and 3 are the values)
User2   1    0 
User3   6    3

Also tried to use, but no help

```
For Col = 0 To RecSet.ColCount - 1
   Sheet4.Cells(Col + 1, 7) = RecSet.FieldValue(Col)
   Sheet4.Cells(Col + 1, 7) = RecSet.FieldValue(Col+1)
Next
```

*EDIT : Please note i am not able to get the User2 and User3 data in that query, but when tested in QC it is showing me the data and there is the data present. Thanks*

Comment: Are you trying to build the results table manually?  Just use the ***Get Data From SQL Server*** wizard and it will take care of all of this for you.

Comment: Hi @iamdave, yes we have a customized table structure so we Get Data will not work for ex User one is called in A1, and the result is called in E1 and G1.

Comment: Is this of any help https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/ff839240.aspx

Comment: Have a look at my answer below.  Build the table using the built in Excel functionality and if necessary, simply change the SQL script held in the connection using your VBA.  ***Do not try to build your table yourself in VBA.  It is a waste of time and effort.***

Comment: Excel can load data from multiple data sources since the 1990s. You don't have to write a VBA macro to do this

Comment: Instead of looping through the record set, have you tried a single line of code like - Sheet4.Range("G1").CopyFromRecordset RecSet

Comment: That's what I was referring to https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/ff839240.aspx. There is also code to include the field names.

Answer (score 3):

Don't try to build your results table yourself in `VBA`, just use the built in functionality already present within Excel.  Click the `Data` tab on the Ribbon, then `From Other Sources` and then `From SQL Server`:

[image]

Follow the steps in the wizard that pops up and you will have your data.  If you want to use a specific query, just select a small table in the wizard and then change the connection properties of the Data Table via the Import Data window that pops up at the end of the wizard:

[image]

Change the `Command Type` to `SQL` and then enter your script into the `Command Text`:

[image]

And you have your table!

---

If you want to be able to change the columns or data that is returned, you can change the `Command Text` using `VBA` and base the various elements of the SQL script on values held within your Worksheet.

Comment: This is a HP ALM database, so this wont work for me :(

Comment: @nishitdey  Then why is this question tagged `SQL-Server`?  Regardless, if you can connect to that database via ODBC, then yes this will work for you.  Select the option `From Microsoft Query` in the `From Other Sources` button instead of `From SQL Server`.  Even if that doesn't work, just attach the connection in your question to a Data Table (Click `Insert` -->  `Table` on the Ribbon) in your Worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution, I was using wrong loop.

```
Set com = QCConnection.Command
com.CommandText = "select RN_TESTER_NAME as 'Tester', sum(case when RN_STATUS='Passed' then cnt else 0 end), sum(case when RN_STATUS='Failed' then cnt else 0 end)from (select count(*) cnt, RN_STATUS,RN_TESTER_NAME from  RUN Where RN_Execution_Date = '5/17/2017'group by RN_STATUS,RN_TESTER_NAME) as RUN group by RN_TESTER_NAME order by RN_TESTER_NAME"
Debug.Print com.CommandText
Set RecSet = com.Execute
x = 1
Do Until RecSet.EOR
   Sheet4.Cells(x, 7) = RecSet.FieldValue(Col)
   Sheet4.Cells(x, 8) = RecSet.FieldValue(Col + 1)
   Sheet4.Cells(x, 9) = RecSet.FieldValue(Col + 2)
RecSet.Next
x = x + 1
Loop
```